# Is it possible to change the tab order of MENU_LOCAL_TASK items on a given page?

Tags: hooks, routes

I have created a couple MENU_LOCAL_TASK items for my advanced search page in Drupal 6, but they appear at the end of the tab list on the far right. I would like my new items to appear first in the list of tabs.

Is there an easy way to accomplish this? I tried setting the weight of my new task items to -99 but this appeared to do nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An easy and correct way is to change the weight as you do. Did you clear menu cache?

Answer (score 3):

You can also use [`hook_menu_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu_alter/7) to change the weight of the links.

And of course, clear the menu cache.

Here's the snippet.

```
    /**
     * Implements hook_menu_alter()
     *
     */
    function mymodule_menu_alter(&$items) {

      $new_weight = 10;

      $items['mymenu/path']['weight'] = $new_weight;

    }
```

Comment: For the benefit of future readers, can you elaborate with a code snippet?